# Need to link directly to a Chrome internal page, from within a page of a Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I just spent the last 7 hours straight trying to find a way to link directly to a Chrome internal page. For now I have given up. I just instructed people to "right-click and open in new tab".

I have tried everything, from html to css to javascript, but nothing is working. Nothing happens when I click the link, even though right-clicking the link and opening it in a new tab works perfect.

Javascript failed attempts:

```
<div class="links">
  <a href="chrome://net-internals/" onclick="window.open('chrome://net-internals/');">TESTAA</a>
</div>
```

and

```
<div class="links">
  <a href="chrome://net-internals/" onclick="window.location('chrome://net-internals/');">TESTAA</a>
</div>
```

There is no error page. Simply nothing happens when you click. If you force it to open in a new tab using `target="_blank"`, it only opens a blank tab.

## UPDATE! SOLVED!

**----- STEP 1-----**

Place the following code in the background.html page (background.html is called in the manifest.json):

```
function openNetInternals() { 
  chrome.tabs.create({url: 'chrome://net-internals/'});
}
```

**----- STEP 2 -----**

Put this code for the link (in the html page):

```
<a href="chrome://net-internals/" onclick="chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().openNetInternals()">Net</a>
```

**----- STEP 3 -----**

Make sure to refresh the extension. 
It will work now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this link available from your extension or from your website? If from extension then try using [chrome.tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html) module:

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: 'chrome://net-internals/'});
```

---

On the background page create function like this one:

```
function openNetInternals() {
   chrome.tabs.create({url: 'chrome://net-internals/'});
}
```

And call it from your custom start page when link is clicked like this:

```
chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().openNetInternals();
```

Relevant docs [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#method-getBackgroundPage).

Comment: Sorry, but permissions have been given to tabs a long time ago. it has no effect.

Comment: I don't understand. What permissions are you talking about?

Comment: nothing. ignore permissions. that is off-topic. I was only answering you telling you i had given the permissions to tabs.

Comment: okay, so let me try to get this straight.

So are telling me to do this: **-----1-----** place the following code in my background.html page (I am using a background.html page): `function openNetInternals() {
   chrome.tabs.create({url: 'chrome://net-internals/'});
}`  **-----2-----** Put this code for my link: `<a href="chrome://net-internals/" onclick="chrome.tabs.create({url: 'chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().openNetInternals();'});">Net</a>` . Is this correct?

Comment: Okay, with that code I get something new at least. Here is the error page. **`This webpage is not found
No webpage was found for the web address: chrome-extension://svbtkuerandomlettersdjkfhsdh/chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().openNetInternals();`**

Comment: You are using it wrong, try: `onclick="chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().openNetInternals();"`.

Comment: Okay I changed step 2 to this, thinking maybe this is what you meant: **-----2-----** Put this code for my link: `<a href="chrome://net-internals/" onclick="chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().openNetInternals();">Net</a>` However, once again nothing at all happens when I click the link.

Comment: Do you get any errors on console (ctrl+shift+j) when you click the link?

Comment: let me check. yes, i do get an error.
 **Uncaught TypeError: Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'openNetInternals'** 
**(anonymous function)** 

**Not allowed to load local resource: chrome://net-internals/**

Comment: OK, so it means that function you were supposed to put on background page (`openNetInternals`) is not there. That is why it is not working. Double check if this function is there, in `<script>` tags etc. and that you have reloaded the extension after making changes to background.html.

Comment: It is definitely there. I double and triple checked to make sure I saved the document. It is within the script tags. I'm going to take a screenshot.

Comment: OK, but have you reloaded the extension after modifying background.html ?

Comment: oh, ok let me reload the extension. ALso here is the screenshot (uploading it now) goo.gl/2dc38

Comment: ahhhhhhhh! =DDDDDDDDDD yyyyyyyyyaaaaaaaaaaaayyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
worksssssssss!!!!!!!!!!!!! 

I am releasing this extension for free, it is a very high quality extension. I was just stuck on this. I would be happy to reference you for your help! How can I reference you?

Comment: I don't think there is need for that :) I was happy to help.

Comment: I get on average 5,000 to 10,000 new users a month for each extension I make.

Comment: I don't think you can. On stackoverflow there is even no way to send messages between users (AFAIK) :)

Comment: well I found lots of other great advice from your profile and gave some up arrows - and honest ones too because it is good info. Reading your posts is like going to college again! =P

Answer (score 2):

to open **chrome://** link in new tab

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: 'chrome://net-internals/'});
```

to open in the same tab

```
chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: true }, function (tabs) {
    var tab_id = tabs[0]['id'];
    chrome.tabs.update(tab_id, {'url':'chrome://net-internals/'});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
<a href="#" onclick="chrome.tabs.create({url: 'chrome://net-internals'});">Net</a>
```

Comment: `Note: This function can be used without requesting the 'tabs' permission in the manifest.` - http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-create

Comment: why is this not working? here is what i used: 
     <a href="chrome://net-internals" target="_blank" onclick="chrome.tabs.create({url: 'chrome://net-internals'});">TESTBB</a>

Comment: Where are you using this link? Context may be important. In a popup window? On the extension configuration page?

Comment: It's not going to work from content scripts for example. You got to have `chrome.tabs` module available (like in background page).

Comment: How can I make it work?
Not in a popup window. Ideally it will open in the same window. it is only the settings page, which located in the same html page as the new tab page, which is a custom one I built. You know how you click a link to go to a website? That's all I want to do, only to go to an internal chrome page.

Comment: Try to `sendRequest` to the background page and from there invoke `chrome.tabs.create`

Comment: oh, let me try to research about sendRequest. Can you give any leads?

Comment: I found this http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-sendRequest and this http://www.toptip.ca/2009/12/google-chrome-extensions-example-of-how.html,  except I am not sure what data I am sending or recieving just so that the link opens the chrome url like chrome://net-internals